# Need alternative to Facebook Open Graph og.likes action for Facebook page

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph

While attempting to publish a like connection between a Facebook user and a Facebook page (using Facebook's Open Graph og.likes action type) within an iOS app I received the following error:

> {"error":{"message":"(#100) Like actions are not yet supported against objects of this type.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}

After doing a little research I found that open graph like actions can not be published against Facebook pages.  My understanding is that my only other option would be to embed the standard like button with a `UIWebView`.

**My question:**
 Is there anything else I can do to create a similar or meaningful open graph connection between a Facebook user and a Facebook page without using a `UIWebView`?

Below is some of my code, I successfully used it to publish a like against a non-Facebook page to verify the issue wasn't something else:

```
    if(isFacebookServiceAuthorized)
{

    NSLog(@"Facebook service is authorized");
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *accessToken = [defaults valueForKey:@"kSHKFacebookAccessToken"];
    id userInfo = [defaults valueForKey:@"kSHKFacebookUserInfo"];
    NSString *userID = [userInfo objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSLog(@"Access Token: %@ and userid: %@", accessToken, userID);

    NSString *devID = FACEBOOK_DEV_USERID
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/og.likes", devID]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request1 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request1 setURL:url];
    [request1 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *body=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"access_token=%@&object=OBJECT_TO_LIKE", accessToken]; 
    [request1 setHTTPBody:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request1 returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"string..:%@",string);

}
```